# Postfix not receiving internet mail

Tags: postfix

I have set up an server running Ubuntu 10.04 and Postfix 2.7 (postfix installed via apt-get). I have an mx record for the domain set up to point to this server as the only mail server for this domain. I have done lookups on the mx record and the fqdn it points to and they both resolve as expected - they were set up over 24 hours ago.

If I telnet to port 25 of my server, I can send mail from the telnet interface and it gets routed as expected, however, if I send mail from an email client, it disappears into the ether - no bounce message to the sender, and the email does not get delivered as expected.

Here are the (I think) pertinent lines from main.cf:

```
myhostname = www1.salonsuites.com
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = www1.salonsuites.com
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 173.230.138.60/32
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

I guess it it worth noting that the while the hostname for the server is set at www1.salonsuites.com, the server is actually set to public ip 173.230.138.60 and the a record is for www2.salonsuites.com. the mx record for www1.salonsuites.com which is the domain for which mail is handled, points to www2.salonsuites.com.

Any suggestions on how to fix the mail delivery problem, and is there a way to generate bounce messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you server is not accessible from the outside:

```
$ nc 173.230.138.60 25
(UNKNOWN) [173.230.138.60] 25 (smtp) : Connection timed out
```

Check your firewall.

Also, check the logs in /var/log/mail.info

Comment: Wow - do I feel stupid. I have my ip accepted on all ports by the firewall, and I had an accept rule for all tcp with a tcp _source_ port of 25, changed it to destination port of 25 and it all works fine.